# dive into python: lambda expressions: logical disambiguation

Tags: python, lambda

I was [reading about lambdas (dive into python)](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html) and I have executed an example code and I got different results than the text states. It's `example 4.21`:

```
processFunc = collapse and (lambda s: " ".join(s.split())) or (lambda s: s)
```

This is my py 2.7 console output:

```
>>> collapse = True
>>> processFunc = collapse and (lambda s: " ".join(s.split())) or (lambda s: s)
>>> processFunc("this   is\na\ttest")
'this is a test'
>>> collapse = False
>>> processFunc("this   is\na\ttest")
'this is a test'
```

As I can see, first lambda expression is returned no matter the `collapse` value is. Is it something wrong with my thinking or python version changed or how come I've got different result than this legendary book states?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set `processFunc` *again*.

The expression is not re-evaluated every time you set `collapse`; it is only calculated *once*. Executing `collapse = False` did not magically change `processFunc` to point to the other lambda.

Simply run the `processFunc =` expression a second time:

```
>>> collapse = True
>>> processFunc = collapse and (lambda s: " ".join(s.split())) or (lambda s: s)
>>> processFunc("this   is\na\ttest")
'this is a test'
>>> collapse = False
>>> processFunc = collapse and (lambda s: " ".join(s.split())) or (lambda s: s)
>>> processFunc("this   is\na\ttest")
'this   is\na\ttest'
```

If you expected `processFunc` to be re-evaluated, you'd need to make that a function or lambda by itself:

```
>>> collapse = True
>>> processFunc = lambda: collapse and (lambda s: " ".join(s.split())) or (lambda s: s)
>>> processFunc()("this is\na\ttest")
'this is a test'
>>> collapse = False
>>> processFunc()("this is\na\ttest")
'this is\na\ttest'
```

But note that you now have to *call* `processFunc()` to return your lambda object, which we then call with an argument. By invoking `processFunc` the expression is reevaluated, the `collapse` name is looked up in the surrounding scope (as a global in this case) and one of the lambdas is returned.

Comment: aaahh... thanks. I thought it works similarly as javascript closures.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz Python closures and lambdas *do* work like javascript closures. However, this would not work in javascript like you seem to expect. Javascript does not magically re-evaluate assignment statements either.

Comment: @Marcin could you please explain this in more detail? I don't understand what is the difference between `js` and `py` here and this seems important... Thanks in advance

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz: closures are different things altogether; you need nested functions which reference names from a surrounding scope. `closure` is not a variable in a surrounding scope, nor is the expression for `processFunc` a nested function.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz: If you defined `processFunc` as a lambda itself, it might work that way: `processFunc = lambda: collapse and (lambda s: " ".join(s.split())) or (lambda s: s)` then `processFunc()("this   is\na\ttest")`.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz There is no difference in this respect, only similarity.`c = true; x = c && funcVar; c = false; alert(x);` will not magically result in an alert box saying "false".